# Unstable log4net emails with a Windows Service on a Windows Server 2003 R3 using Exchange Server

Tags: windows-services, log4net, windows-server-2003, exchange-server

I am running a **Windows Service on a Windows Server 2003 R2. We are using Exchange Server to send out the emails.**

I am using log4net.dll 1.2.11.0.

**I have situation where log4net sometimes sends emails and sometimes don't eventhough no changes has been made to the set up.**

**All the other log4net logging works very fine. And as said sometimes the application sends out emails and some times it don't, having made no change to the application.**

All my methods are in try-catch clauses, but I don't get any errors.

**When I run the the Windows Service on my local machine, the log4net email always works**, and as said on the remote server, **sometimes the log4net email works, sometimes it don't, having made no changes to the setup.**

I am using **log4net.Internal.Debug** and have a **System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener file** where stuff is written to.
Scanning thorugh this file I haven't noticed anything in particular, but I don't know what specific to look for.

**Any ideas about what the problem is or what to do?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SMTP appender cannot send an email it would log an exception with this text: *Error occurred while sending e-mail notification.* This would be visible if internal debugging is enabled. Maybe you have filters or something like that configured that prevents log4net from sending an email.

You could download the source code of log4net and add extra logging to the SMTP appender to find out if the "SendMail" method of the appender gets called at all. If it does and no email and no error is shown, then we need to assume that the exchange server somehow swallows the emails. If the appender is not triggered, then you need to review your filter / buffer / threshold configuration.

Alternatively you could try to use the `SmtpPickupDirAppender`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Stefan Egli :) The funny thing is that sometimes log4net works fine and sends out the emails and sometimes it don't, having made no changes to the config. When I tested the same code on my local machine it always worked. But out in production, it's unstable, sometimes works, sometimes don't. I am using log4net.Internal.Debug, but I haven't yet noticed the Error occurred while sending e-mail notification. message. It seems like there was a tendency that the emails was not working when the exchange server might be most busy. I might look into SmtpPickupDirAppender.

Comment: I have made some test with a list of emails to be send out to, one of them one of the companies own email addresses. It turns out that the emails to the yahoo accounts gets deliverd fine, whereas the email to the company's own email address does not get delivered. Currently that seems to by my problem. That is something about the company's own email addresses which makes them unstable.

Comment: Ok. So now you at least know that your application is not the problem. :)

Comment: Hi Hi Stefan Egli, thank you once again for your assistence!
I have now found the source of the problem.
And I am somewhat embarrassed to tell what it is.
It turns out that the emails to the company's own email addresses sometimes ended up in the spam folder. I am embarassed to tell this.
It was not always that the emails ended up in the spam folder, but sometimes.
I am a little unsure what I should mark as the answer to the question.

Comment: I guess you can mark the question as answered since it pointed you in the right direction and can be useful for others with similar problems.